# Alert() from JavaScript is not displaying

Tags: javascript, fiddler

We use Lawson software.  It is proprietary and we do not have access to the code.  Recently, there has been an update to Lawson and we are not seeing the Alert() windows that come from JavaScript.  Lawson people are asking us to figure it out.  I downloaded Fiddler to see if I could tell if the event was firing.  I have very little Fiddler experience and don't know if I'm approaching how to answer this question correctly.  How can I tell if a JavaScript event is firing without debugging the source code? Would Fiddler be able to tell me that?

Comment: Alert popups are not directly caused by events. JavaScript code in the browser explicitly *asks* for a popup by calling `alert()`. That may happen in an event handler, but it may happen at any other time as well.

Comment: Is there any way to see if the alert has been called in Fiddler?

Comment: I doubt it; an `alert()` call does not involve an HTTP request to the  server; it's something completely inside the browser.

Comment: What is the name of the event in question?

Answer (score 2):

No, Fiddler won't be able to tell you that. Fiddler is a tool used for viewing HTTP requests, but javascript alerts are unrelated to HTTP requests. I'm not aware of a way you can debug javascript code in an arbitrary application without access to the source code.